# How to make the KVM enable CPU flags（sse4_2）to the guest

Tags: virtualization, qemu, linux-kvm

My host is CentOs6.8, and the kernel is 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64.  I have installed KVM on it and I use KVM create my guests. And my guests works fine.

Now, I run some software or code on my guests.  I get the error like this:

> ```
> /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.13.0-1.cdh5.13.0.p0.29/lib/kudu/sbin/kudu-tserver 
>  --tserver_master_addrs=sz-5-centos224,sz-5-centos238 
>  --flagfile=/opt/cm-5.13.0/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/8442-kudu-KUDU_TSERVER/gflagfile
> WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
> F0802 17:24:26.397984  5041 init.cc:84] Check failed: _s.ok() 
> Bad status: Not implemented: The CPU on this system (QEMU Virtual CPU 
>   version (cpu64-rhel6)) does not support the SSE4.2 instruction set which is 
>   required for running Kudu. If you are running inside a 
>   VM, you may need to enable SSE4.2 pass-through.`
> ```

From the error I can see that cause the guests did not have the sse4.2, so, how can make the guests enable sse4.2? Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem as you, the following steps solved my problem:

1. I enabled the sse4.2 for qemu64 cpu:

   `qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm  -cpu qemu64,+ssse3,+sse4.1,+sse4.2`
2. Made sure that the guest uses qemu64 cpu for virtualization by adding the following element to vm xml:

   `<cpu mode='custom' match='exact' check='partial'>
       <model fallback='allow'>qemu64</model>
       <feature policy='require' name='sse4.2'/>
       <feature policy='disable' name='svm'/>
   </cpu>`

   I had to disable svm because it was not supported on my host. The command you could use to edit a vm xml is `virsh edit vm_name`
3. Destroying the vm and building it from ground up:
   `virsh destroy vm_name`
   `virsh start vm_name` 
   *Note that virsh shutdown or restarting the vm does not apply the xml changes to the vm. You have to destroy it in order to changes to take effect*
4. With `lscpu` or `cat /proc/cpuinfo/` in the flags section you could assure that the sse4.2 is enabled on your guest.

---

useful links:
  - https://ahelpme.com/howto/qemu-full-virtualization-cpu-emulations-enable-disable-cpu-flags-instruction-sets/
  - http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Tuning_KVM
  - https://github.com/vagrant-libvirt/vagrant-libvirt/issues/667